# select files in app dir bombs explorer. node, typescript, aliens related?

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have a windows directory that when doing development is monitored by gulp to pick up changes in typescript files and built and move transpiled and map files to another directory. This behavior should quit when I quit the process. The weird part is at no time can I access or even hover over files in that directory without bombing windows explorer. I can reboot and go to the directory and the same thing happens. HOW? Why? I have no start up tasks or services targeting that folder.

What is messing with my folder?

Comment: Try asking this on superuser.com. The problem sounds more like an IT issue than a programming one.

Comment: you may be right. I found that .ts files are transport streams and windows 10 has an issue scanning them. Case of annoying mistaken identity. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-file-explorer-always-scans-a-ts-file-on/ddd6d412-ba2a-48c2-8fa2-64a9c07d502c